# Testing non-resource actions in Ruby on Rails

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've added the following in my config/routes.rb file:

```
match 'login' => 'sessions#new'
match 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
match 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create'
match 'auth/failure' => 'sessions#new'
match 'sessions/delegate' => 'sessions#delegate'
```

This allows me to have my own custom login form that authenticates through OmniAuth and an OpenID provider in this case. The routes and the code works well, but I have a problem with writing functional tests for the SessionsController.

Testing the new action works well:

```
test "show login form when requesting new session" do
  get :new
  assert_response :success
end
```

But testing the create action gives me an exception: ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"create"}

The code is like this:

```
test "create session adds logged in user" do
  request.env['rack.auth'] = {:uid => auths(:one).open_id, :provider => 'open_id'}
  post :create
  # assert that create action did it's things here
end
```

I've tried to replace the post with a get but the result is the same.
Why is the one action found, and not the other?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it's getting confused because you're not supplying the :provider key from the match pattern. You might find it clearer to specify names for these non-resourceful routes, like:

```
match 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create', as: 'callback'
```

This will allow you to `post callback_path(provider: whatever)` in your test, *I think* :-)

Comment: Nope, then I get `ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"/auth/open_id/callback"}` But it was a good suggestion...

Comment: Ok, I couldn't remember if url helper methods were allowed in functional tests. I guess not. Does `post :create, provider: 'open_id'` work any better?